# AutoLayout - Resizing UILabel to its Superview and sizing it

Tags: ios, ios6, uilabel, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a `UICollectionView` which contains some cells.

Each cell holds one `UILabel` within it. Within the label is one letter, it acts as a tile (as such). When more cells are added to the `UICollectionView` the `UICollectionViewCells` change size with the following:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                 layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
 sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    NSLog(@"the word array count is: %i",self.wordArray.count);
    if (self.wordArray.count <= 5) {
        return CGSizeMake(50,50);
    } else if (self.wordArray.count <= 6 ) {
        return CGSizeMake(30, 30);
    } else if (self.wordArray.count <= 8 ) {
        return CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    } else {
        return CGSizeMake(100,100);
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do now is re-size the `UILabel` within the cell each time the layout is changed. How can I fit the labels size to the cells size using `AutoLayout`? Also how can I update the font size based on the `UILabel` size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-creating this in IB worked. I was able to set the constraints for the horizontal/vertical to 0/required for the sides of the label in the cell itself and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set something like the following layout constraints:

```
NSDictionary *viewDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label);
NSDictionary *insetMetrics = @{
    @"left" : @(10.0f),
    @"right" : @(10.0f),
    @"top" : @(10.0f),
    @"bottom" : @(10.0f)
};

[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(left)-[label]-(right)-|" options:kNilOptions metrics:insetMetrics views:viewDictionary]];
[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(top)-[label]-(bottom)-|" options:kNilOptions metrics:insetMetrics views:viewDictionary]];
```

Text in a UILabel can automatically shrink if you set the correct properties (see the [UILabel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)).  So if you set the font size initially to the size you'd like for the largest cell, as the label shrinks, the text will shrink with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I have added 'self.letterLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;' aswell as the above constraints to the cell init method.

Comment: Strange, it works for me.  Did you set the `minimumScaleFactor`?

Comment: Yes in IB strangely. I think the issue is more where this should be setup. What I need is for the label frame to match the cell frame, and the text in the label to scale to that effect. should it be setup (as above) in the cells init, or within the 'cellForItemAtIndexPath'?

Comment: Can you do it all in the interface builder?  I quickly tested by making a nib with a view, placing a label in the view, and setting up the auto layout constraints (and minimum scale factor) as outlined above.  Then if you resize the view, you should see the label resize with it, and when the label gets too small for the text, the text will resize with it as well.

Comment: How would I setup these constraints in IB? This is the first time I have used AutoLayout and the docs are lacking.

Comment: This is a pretty good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35930/discussion-between-stuartm-and-eric)

Comment: I have added a link to the temp project